# java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working with threads. However when I try to start a thread, I get a Exception. In concrete java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException. My code is:

```
public void readCommand() {
    readThread = new Thread("Thread for reading") {
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                readBuffer = usbservice.receiveData();
                put(readBuffer);
            }
        }
    };
    readThread.start();
}
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: are you sure that only one place where you have readThread.start()?

Comment: Where does the exception occur and what does it say?  Normally this happens if you try to start the thread more than once.

Comment: Hmmm, starting a thread will throw that exception if the thread is already started, but this does not appear to be the case in your code.

Comment: it would definitely help if you could post a stack trace or something.

Comment: I review the code and only call start() once. Also the method readCommand is only called once.

Comment: I have been searching for several calls to method start, but I do not find anyone. I only call once, I am sure!!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You are storing the thread in a field. If the method is called in two threads, the `readThread.start()` can be called twice for the same thread.  You need to ensure readCommand is not called multiple times and perhaps not start the readThread again if its already running. e.g. you can synchronized the method and check readThread before you start.

Comment: So you are saying that if there are two threads and each thread invokes this method , the readThread field will be shared ? Because each time the method is invoked, a new reference is passed to this Thread object and it gets aloocated on the stack for each thread .

Comment: @Nishant_Singh Close, `readThread` is not on the local stack, so if it is called concurrently, multiple threads can attempt to start the same one.

Answer (score 24):

A thread will throw the exception when calling start if the thread's state (as retrieved by `Thread.currentThread().getState()` is anything other than `NEW`.

The source;

```
public synchronized void start() {
    /*
     * A zero status value corresponds to state "NEW".
     */
    if (threadStatus != 0)
        throw new IllegalThreadStateException();
    group.add(this);
    start0();
    if (stopBeforeStart) {
        stop0(throwableFromStop);
    }
}
```

This means, your thread is in one of the other states, `RUNNABLE`, `BLOCKED`, `WAITING`, `TIMED_WAITING` or `TERMINATED`.

You could have a look at the state of the threads via a thread dump or JConsole to see what yours is doing. You can programmatically take a thread dump right before the call to `start` using something like [tempus-fugit](http://tempusfugitlibrary.org/documentation/threading/dumps/) if that helps.

UPDATE: In response to your comments, if you interrupt a thread which in your case, I assume will set the `running` flag to false, the thread will still be `RUNNABLE`. To 'resume' work on the thread (again, I'm assuming that's what you want to do), you would change the `running` flag again. Calling `start` will fail because it's already started. You could also let the thread die on interruption and then just create a new instance of a `Thread` and "start" that one as an alternative.

Comment: I check it and the state is NEW:

Comment: When I stop application I interrupt the threads and when I restart application, the state in RUNNABLE.

Comment: I've updated to answer to include the source of the Thread class. This is the only way the exception can be thrown here so perhaps its being caused from some other place? or perhaps you're checking it too early? Perhaps you could prepare a self contained test/sample so we can reproduce...

Comment: you can't restart a "stopped" thread by calling start again on it! you'll need to use another thread (a new one) or in the case of most thread pools, the same thread can be re-used to do stuff... but that's another question :)

Comment: But I do not undestand why the first time that I start thread, the state is RUNNABLE.

Comment: Once a thread has started, it'll move from NEW (ready to start) to RUNNABLE which indicates it's execution can be scheduled by the OS. Think of its as potentially-RUNNING...

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at oracle documentation page about [Thread.start()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--)

```
public void start()
```

*Causes this thread to begin execution;* the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread.

The result is that two threads are running concurrently: the current thread (which returns from the call to the start method) and the other thread (which executes its run method).

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

***Throws:
`IllegalThreadStateException` - if the thread was already started.***

In multi-threaded environment, you have to make sure that above `Thread` is started exactly once. If you are trying `start()` on a `Thread`, which has been already started, you are bound to get above exception.

Answer (score 3):

If the thread has already been started, you need to use `run()` instead of `start()`.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the call process is:

- From main method: controller.main(usbservice);
- In controller object:

  ```
  @Override
  public void main(Object argv) {
      if(this.writer == null)
          this.writer = new CommandWriting(usbservice);
      if(this.reader == null)
          this.reader = new CommandReading(usbservice);
      reader.readCommand();
  }
  ```
- In object reader is the readCommand method.

Then, it is only called once.

Answer (score 0):

just Initialize Your Thread with

```
 Thread abc =new Thread(){
}
```

& call start() when you need multiple times after thread finish task.

Hope this works for you