# Running Thread's in Java Throws an Exception

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am trying to create a game and have come across a bizarre issue with the way I choose to run my Threads

The way I have it set up is that each pertinent class has a `Thread` Object, who's `run()` function runs the code once. Each is called once every frame.

However whenever I try to run the code I get a `java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException` and I have no clue why.

Here's an adaptation of the problematic code:

```
public class Test { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while(true) {

            ThreadA.run(args);
            ThreadB.run(args);

        }

    }

    private static class ThreadA {

        private static Thread thread = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                System.out.println("A");

            }

        };

        public static void run(String[] args) {

            thread.start();

        }

    }
    private static class ThreadB {

        private static Thread thread = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                System.out.println("B");

            }

        };

        public static void run(String[] args) {

            thread.start();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: simple RTFM case - documentation of [start](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#start()): "It is never legal to start a thread more than once. ... `IllegalThreadStateException` - if the thread was already started."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315941/java-lang-illegalthreadstateexception)

Comment: and `while (true)` will run very often (and fast)....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
while(true) {
  ThreadA.run(args);
  ThreadB.run(args);
}
```

This will loop infinitely. It is never legal to start a thread more than once - even if it has completed. `thread.isAlive()` won't help you here - if you want to run it again, make a new instance.

Comment: Even after ensuring ```thread.isAlive == false``` there is no change

Comment: @BenjaminBanerjee, You're missing the point. You are not allowed to `start()` the same `Thread` instance more than one time. The `isAlive` state is irrelevant. The second call to `start()` will _always_ fail.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling Thread#start over and over. It's throwing IllegalStateException because the threads internal status must be equal to 0 for it to start. Anything other than 0 means it has run, is running, or is disposed of.

Answer (score 1):

As per [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()):

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a
> thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

If you intend to run the threads infinitely, you can do it as

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadA.run(args);
        ThreadB.run(args);
    }

    private static class ThreadA {
        private static Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("A");
                }
            }
        };

        public static void run(String[] args) {
            thread.start();
        }

    }

    private static class ThreadB {
        private static Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("B");
                }
            }
        };

        public static void run(String[] args) {
            thread.start();
        }
    }
}
```